# Pogo Pins Schematic

Tags: usb, schematics, 5v

I have a Galaxy Nexus phone which has [pogo pins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pogo_pin):
[image]

I have determined which pins are PWR and GND but I don't know what the third pin is. I assume it is for the dock feature of the phone so it knows that it has been inserted into a dock. I'm not sure if I should just apply another 5V to it, put it to ground, or what because I can't find an schematics online for it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Those are not spring loaded, so I'd call those contacts for pogo pins in the dock to mate with, rather than pogo pins themselves.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The middle pin is the "sense" pogo pin in the Galaxy Nexus: The phone sends out a 100 millisecond pulse on this pin, then waits for three pulsed responses, to sense what it has been connected to.

From `board-tuna-pogo.c`:

```
/* The below constants are in milliseconds */
#define POGO_WAKE_PERIOD                100
#define POGO_ID_PERIOD_TIMEOUT          750
#define POGO_ID_DESKDOCK                50
#define POGO_ID_CARDOCK                 100
#define POGO_ID_CHARGER                 50
#define POGO_ID_USB                     100
#define POGO_ID_AUDIO                   50
#define POGO_ID_NO_AUDIO                100
#define POGO_ENTER_SPDIF_WAIT_PERIOD    100
#define POGO_ID_PERIOD_TOLERANCE        20
#define POGO_DET_DEBOUNCE               80
```

The three response pulses expected are:

- POGO_ID_DESKDOCK or POGO_ID_CARDOCK
- POGO_ID_CHARGER or POGO_ID_USB
- POGO_ID_AUDIO or POGO_ID_NO_AUDIO